# How do I add a class to a section in omega?

Tags: 7, theming

Here is the original source:

```
<section id="section-content" class="section section-content">
```

I want to add some class to it:

```
<section id="section-content" class="section section-content my-custom-class">
```

I've tried a hook_page_alter() but either I haven't been able to zero in on the specific element or I'm attaching the classes incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but I am pretty sure you just need to put this in mytheme/preprocess/preprocess-section.inc:

```
function mytheme_alpha_preprocess_section (&$variables)
{
  $variables['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'my-custom-class';
}
```

If you look at section.tpl.php, just `$attributes` gets printed out.  `alpha_process()` flattens `$variables['attributes_array']` into `$attributes`.

Though, given that the header, content, and footer sections are unique, you probably don't need to explicitly add a class.  You can also add classes to the zone and zone wrappers inside each section directy with the UI at admin/appearance/settings/mytheme, or just replace "section" with "zone" in the code above.